# Notice: Undefined index: province in D:\wamp\www\PDO\sampleCRUD\update.php on line 13?

Tags: pdo

I have here the page for update.php my problem was I keep getting this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: province in D:\wamp\www\PDO\sampleCRUD\update.php on line 13
```

every time I select this value "---" in my dropdown list it keeps showing this error but if select the rest of the list in the dropdown there's no error I tried to set the province but I still getting this error.

**here my code for update.php**

```
<?php
 include_once 'dbconfig.php';
  $username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '';
  $password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : '';
  $province = isset($_GET['province']) ? $_GET['province'] : '';

   if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
   {
   $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $province = $_POST['province'];

   if($crud->update($user_id,$username,$password,$province))
   {
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Record was updated Successfully!');</script>";
   }
   else
   {
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!'); </script>";
   }
   }

   if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
   {
   $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
   extract($crud->getID($user_id)); 
   }

   ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>Survey Update Landholdings</title>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/icon.ico"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">

  <div class="container">
   <p><strong>Survey Update</strong></p>
    <br />
     <div id="Survey-Update">
       <form method='post'>
        <table class='table table-bordered'>

          <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" required></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='password' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $password; ?>" required></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Province</td>
             <?php
                include_once 'dbconfig.php';

                $sql = "SELECT username FROM sample";
                $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
                    {
                    ?>
             <td><select class='form-control' name='province'>
               <option selected="selected" disabled>---</option>
                <?php foreach ($results as $row)
                    {
                 ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </select>

                <?php
                    }
                ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="2">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update">
              <span class="edit"></span>Update</button>
              <a href="index.php" onClick="self.close()"> &nbsp; CANCEL</a>
            </td>
          </tr>

       </table>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**the error is in this line**

```
$province = $_POST['province'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<option selected="selected" disabled>---</option>
```

to

```
<option selected="selected" value="" disabled>---</option>
```

to send an empty value for province instead of none.

---

Edit: the above code does not work.

The issue here is the disabled and selected="selected". It seems, disabled options don't get submitted. 
If you want to stick with disabled and selected I suggest using

`$province = isset($_POST['province']) ? $_POST['province'] : ''`;

Comment: i change the code according to what you suggested but i still getting the error..

Comment: so, what do i need to do?

Comment: i already figure it out..now it's working.thanks for the advice..i just remove the "disabled"